# How to remove warning about samesite in Chrome using a React App with msal Authentication

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, azure-ad-msal, samesite

We have a react app and we are using msal authentication towards AAD. The first time the user logs in the application and we call `acquireTokenSilent` to aquire the token, we get this warning

[image]

we tried to call :  `document.cookie = "cross-site-cookie=bar, SameSite=None, Secure";`

but we continue to get this warning.

When the app is deployed in an azure service it's even worse.  `acquireTokenSilent`returns a `ClientAuthError Token renewal operation failed due to time out`. If the user refreshes the page then it acquires the token and the warning goes away.

How we can remove this warning?
Is the `ClientAuthError` that we get related to this warning (this happens only after we get this warning)?

Comment: I am also getting the same warning in my angular application

Comment: Do any of these links help? [Samesite impact on auth](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity/blogs/impact-on-authentication-from-samesite-changes-in-chrome/) and [how to handle samesite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-handle-samesite-cookie-changes-chrome-browser?tabs=dotnet)?

Comment: Read this excellent article on Samesite cookies: [SameSite cookie recipes](https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes/)

Comment: Maybe this is the expected behavior from msal  https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1037#issuecomment-573174503

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login.microsoftonline.com and login.live.com were updated late 2019 to correctly set the SameSite=None flag on the cookies required for cross domain requests.  We have many other cookies that are not required cross-domain, however, and those are left untagged to reduce the amount of changes we put into a live system.   This can cause some warnings in the Chrome console, which you can safely ignore for the login.microsoftonline.com and login.live.com domains.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find where this cookie is originally set and provide an appropriate `SameSite` attribute. Remember - `SameSite=None; Secure` is only required if you **do want** this cookie sent in cross-site / third-party contexts. If the cookie is only intended for your own site, consider using `SameSite=Lax` or even `SameSite=Strict`.

**Updated** Commenters rightly pointed out the listed domain in the error is clearly for `microsoftonline.com` which is not the submitter's site. My advice would only apply if the submitter was talking about their own site's cookies.

Comment: Maybe this is the expected behavior from msal  https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1037#issuecomment-573174503

Comment: @rowan_m - Note that this is a federated IDP flow, so login.microsoftonline.com is not owned by them. This is a false positive.